# mysql query to count the number of events happened today

Tags: mysql

i want to display the number of events that ended today.
My query is

```
SELECT * FROM cyclerconfigs where endDate > CURDATE()-1;
```

but it is showing the results from previous day also.

[image: result]

Comment: Of course it is. You asked it to show that. `curdate()-1` means 'take the current date and subtract 1 from it`. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM cyclerconfigs where DATE(endDate) = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM cyclerconfigs where endDate = CURDATE()

Comment: Won't this fail unless `endDate` is precisely midnight on this day?